# How do I find out which processes are causing the most disk activity?

Tags: windows-xp, performance, performance-monitor

I am hoping to find a way to do more performance monitoring--specifically, I hope that monitoring disk activity on a per-process basis will help me decide which programs are causing the most trouble (aside from the AV).   I'd rather avoid a shotgun approach.

For windows XP, is there a process monitor that can give me a solid idea of which processes are slowing me down by causing the most page faults, etc?  Thanks!

Comment: http://superuser.com/questions/175365/how-can-i-figure-out-what-process-is-constantly-accessing-my-hard-drive-in-window

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Perhaps enabling the I/O reads and writes in the task manager **(**<kbd>ctrl</kbd>**+**<kbd>shift</kbd>**+**<kbd>esc</kbd>**)**.  When looking at the processes in task manager select View then Select Columns.  Look for the I/O read optiona nd I/O write option and click them.

This is what I get:

[image]

Comment: Thanks! This is just what I needed.  I ended up using Page Faults and PF Delta, for the most part.

Comment: Network communication is IO as well. With heavy usage of internet this makes the numbers quite uncertain.

Comment: @TomášZato this is true, but if a process is heavily spamming a disk drive, you'll more than likely be able to detect it using this method.

Answer (score 5):

While I prefer the accepted answer, there is another way with the existing task manager.

- Task manager > Performance (tab) > Resource Monitor (button) > Disk (tab)

[image]

Comment: This does get the "True" read/write IO to the disk drives.  If have a lot of network or other IO traffic, the accepted answer may be masked by those other operations.  This is a better option in this case.

Answer (score 3):

I like the freeware [Process Explorer](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653.aspx).  It provides a bit more detail than the Windows Task Manager, including per-process I/O graphs.  Great for immediately spotting processes doing a lot of disk I/O.