# Windows 7 hard drive constantly running

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Tool which finds which process is causing the heavy hard drive activity?](https://superuser.com/questions/196366/tool-which-finds-which-process-is-causing-the-heavy-hard-drive-activity)

I'm running Win7 x64 Ultimate on a quad-core AMD with 8GB of RAM and a 500GB drive.

Something is constantly hammering the hard drive to the point where the noise is become annoying.

I've tried increasing the page file size to the recommended 12GB, which hasn't had much, if any, effect.

Any suggestions? My two other desktops and my laptop don't seem to suffer from this problem.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Tool which finds which process is causing the heavy hard drive activity?](http://superuser.com/questions/196366/tool-which-finds-which-process-is-causing-the-heavy-hard-drive-activity) and/or [How can I find out what is using the hard disk?](http://superuser.com/questions/98169/how-can-i-find-out-what-is-using-the-hard-disk) and/or [hard drive activity by program?](http://superuser.com/questions/69326/hard-drive-activity-by-program)